# Make text ellipsis in Charts

Tags: javascript, echarts

How Can I make text ellipsis when text is out of box in ECharts v5.

I couldn't find useful API from [doc](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-custom.itemStyle)

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/profile-forked-y6ys2s?file=/index.js)

This code is to add text in rectangle box

```js
(
    rectShape && {
      type: "rect",
      transition: ["shape"],
      shape: rectShape,
      style: api.style({
        text: api.value(3),
        textFill: "blue",
        textAlign: "right"
      })
    }
  );
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`textStyle.ellipsis`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#textStyle.ellipsis)?

Comment: yeah, it didnt work for the text in the rectangle (box)